# Unity3D + Kinect Collision detection between character controller and object

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, kinect, collision

I'm currently working on a simple "football" game where two players are playing against each other. They have a goal and they have to put the ball into the other one's goal. Their movement are tracked with a Kinect.

Unfortunately, I experiencing some difficulties with the collisions. I've attached a Rigidbody to the feet and the hands of each characters so that they can kick and hit the ball and it works more or less. The problem is that the feet and the hands are turning on themselves and I cannot figure out why. Moreover, I want to add a force when a character kicks (or hits) the ball. To do so, I used http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/CharacterController.OnControllerColliderHit.html but it does not work. I added a Debug.Log("foobar"), but it does not log anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yay! I solved the problem using trigger. I checked the "Is Trigger" for the feet and the hands and handled the trigger with the following code:

```
public float speed;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    Rigidbody body = hit.collider.attachedRigidbody;
    if (body == null || body.isKinematic)
        return;

    body.AddForce(Vector3.forward * speed);
}
```

It solved all the problems at once!